# Java Exception CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect

Tags: java, jsp, exception, jikes

I am getting this error while the server tries to generate a jsp file. We are using our very own Application server (proprietary tool). The server will download the files from a region (say QA) on which my application depends on.

I know the root cause for this error - Classpath is too long, but I dont know how my downloaded files/ jar are getting included to the classpath string, which makes its length greater than **32767** characters. (See the Screenshot)

I need a workaround to solve this problem.

Note : I have come across so many threads reg this issue. They are related to working with eclipse. I don't use eclipse at all. I am just using a text editor.. Any Idea on how to fix this issue.

[image: SS1]

[image: SS2]

Thanks in advance

```
    [Error] arch.presentation.JSPResource generating jsp page: generating jsp servlet '__jsp_error__.jsp' org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile clas
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:105)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:344)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler.generateClass(AntCompiler.java:288)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:301)
        at arch.tools.JspC.JspC.processFile(JspC.java:458)
        at arch.tools.JspC.JspC.parseFile(JspC.java:571)
        at arch.presentation.JSPResource.compile_if_needed(JSPResource.java:300)
        at arch.presentation.JSPResource.compile(JSPResource.java:497)
        at arch.presentation.JSPResource.process(JSPResource.java:384)
        at arch.presentation.JSPResource.process(JSPResource.java:375)
        at arch.presentation.JSPResource.showErrorPage(JSPResource.java:157)
        at arch.presentation.JSPResource.compile_if_needed(JSPResource.java:336)
        at arch.presentation.JSPResource.compile(JSPResource.java:497)
        at arch.presentation.JSPResource.process(JSPResource.java:384)
        at arch.presentation.JSPResource.process(JSPResource.java:375)
        at arch.presentation.beans.WebApplication$FilterChain.doFilter(WebApplication.java:519)
        at arch.subsessions.Filter.doFilter(Filter.java:68)
        at arch.presentation.beans.WebApplication$FilterChain.doFilter(WebApplication.java:513)
        at pershing.netxoffice.amps.common.servlet.AmpsCommonFilter.doFilter(AmpsCommonFilter.java:80)
        at arch.presentation.beans.WebApplication$FilterChain.doFilter(WebApplication.java:513)
        at arch.subsessions.SubmitPostFilter.doFilter(SubmitPostFilter.java:58)
        at arch.presentation.beans.WebApplication$FilterChain.doFilter(WebApplication.java:513)
        at arch.presentation.beans.WebApplication._findAndDoFilter(WebApplication.java:740)
        at arch.presentation.beans.WebApplication._findAndDoFilter(WebApplication.java:702)
        at arch.presentation.beans.WebApplication._doServletFilterForRequest(WebApplication.java:691)
        at arch.presentation.beans.WebApplication.processResource(WebApplication.java:1686)
        at arch.presentation.beans.WebApplication.processRequest(WebApplication.java:2992)
        at arch.servletengine.Provider.processRequest(Provider.java:447)
        at arch.no.engine.Context.processRequest(Context.java:68)
        at arch.no.engine.HttpConnector.processRequest(HttpConnector.java:58)
        at arch.no.http.Response.prepare(Response.java:565)
        at arch.no.http.Response._execute(Response.java:2008)
        at arch.no.http.Response.startServletRequest(Response.java:1938)
        at arch.no.http.Response.run(Response.java:1906)
        at arch.no.http.HttpThreadPool._run(HttpThreadPool.java:35)
        at arch.util.ThreadPool._runLoopBody(ThreadPool.java:221)
        at arch.util.ThreadPool._runForThread(ThreadPool.java:238)
        at arch.util.ThreadPool.access$000(ThreadPool.java:3)
        at arch.util.ThreadPool$1.run(ThreadPool.java:96)
Caused by: Error running C:\Data\jdk6\bin\javac.exe compiler
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.DefaultCompilerAdapter.executeExternalCompile(DefaultCompilerAdapter.java:509)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.JavacExternal.execute(JavacExternal.java:61)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1065)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:882)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler.generateClass(AntCompiler.java:257)
        ... 37 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Data\jdk6\bin\javac.exe": CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:459)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:832)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:447)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:461)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.DefaultCompilerAdapter.executeExternalCompile(DefaultCompilerAdapter.java:506)
        ... 41 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:81)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:452)
        ... 50 more




[Error] org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler Environment: Compile: javaFileName=/C:/Data/inautilus/Regions/qa/downloaded/pershing.netxoffice.amps.common/work/pershing.netxoffice.amps.common.WebApplication/__jsp__//amps_002fcommon/
    classpath=C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\pershing.netxoffice.amps.common\work\pershing.netxoffice.amps.common.WebApplication\__jsp__;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\pershing.netxoffice.amps.common\classes;C:\
are.thirdparty\lib\ais-client.jar;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\middleware.thirdparty\lib\aqapi.jar;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\middleware.thirdparty\lib\CL3Export.jar;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded
.4.57/arch.core.jdbc/lib/driver_getter/;C:/Data/arch.inautilus.full.7400.7.4.57/arch.core.jdbc/lib/oracle/db_config.py;C:/Data/arch.inautilus.full.7400.7.4.57/arch.core.jdbc/lib/oracle/ojdbc14.jar;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\dow
7400.7.4.57\arch.ejbpersistence\lib\hibernate3.jar;C:\Data\arch.inautilus.full.7400.7.4.57\arch.ejbpersistence\public.jar;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\middleware.appln.MLGSyncService\classes;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\q
mon\lib\icepublisher.jar;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\com.inautix.netx.alertcommon\lib\icesocket.jar;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\com.inautix.netx.alertcommon\lib\iceutil.jar;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\dow
voiceware.dialer\lib\util.jar;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\arch.struts2\classes;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\arch.struts2\lib;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\arch.struts2\lib\antlr.jar;C:\Data\inauti
sper.jar;C:\Data\arch.inautilus.full.7400.7.4.57\arch.core.servletengine\lib\jersey-client-1.4.jar;C:\Data\arch.inautilus.full.7400.7.4.57\arch.core.servletengine\lib\jersey-core-1.4.jar;C:\Data\arch.inautilus.full.7400.7.4.57\ar
.samlcore\lib\xmlsec-1.4.3.jar;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\system.sso.common.ssoutils\classes;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\system.entitlements.cache\classes;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\arch.cohe
autilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\arch.coherence.cache.containers\classes;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\arch.coherence.grid.enterprisesession\classes;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\arch.coherence.grid.enterpriseses
achment\classes;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\netxoffice.attachment\public.jar;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\imaging.webservices\classes;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\imaging.webservices\lib;C:\Data\
aging\lib\poi-ooxml-3.7-20101029.jar;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\com.pershing.imaging\lib\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.7-20101029.jar;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\com.pershing.imaging\lib\xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar;C:/Data/
common.dbservices\lib\spring-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\pershing.common.dbservices\lib\spring-expression-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\pershing.common.dbservices\lib
ed\netxoffice.userdata\classes;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\netxoffice.userdata\public.jar;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\arch.workflowservices\classes;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\arch.workflowserv
downloaded\com.inautix.netx.alert\lib\icebalancer.jar;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\com.inautix.netx.alert\lib\icecommon.jar;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\com.inautix.netx.alert\lib\icedbdao.jar;C:\Data\inauti
tilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\netxoffice.enterpriserichgrid\classes;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\netxoffice.enterpriserichgrid\lib;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\netxoffice.enterpriserichgrid\lib\itext-1.4.6.jar
ib\streambuffer.jar;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\formsmgmt.laspdf\lib\war-classes.jar;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\formsmgmt.laspdf\lib\woodstox-core-asl.jar;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\formsmgmt
ation.rsa\public.jar;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\middleware.common.AsyncGateway\classes;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\middleware.common.AsyncGateway\public.jar;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\eservic
ownloaded\arch.jsf\lib\commons-digester-1.8.jar;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\arch.jsf\lib\commons-discovery-0.4.jar;C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\arch.jsf\lib\jetty-util-7.0.0pre3.jar;C:\Data\inautilus\Region
inautilus.full.7400.7.4.57\arch.core\lib\commons-fileupload-1.0-beta-1.jar;c:\data\arch.inautilus.full.7400.7.4.57\arch.core\lib\commons-logging-api.jar;c:\data\arch.inautilus.full.7400.7.4.57\arch.core\lib\concurrent.jar;c:\data
inautilus.full.7400.7.4.57\arch.core\lib\extensions\axis.jar;c:\data\arch.inautilus.full.7400.7.4.57\arch.core\lib\extensions\dom.jar;c:\data\arch.inautilus.full.7400.7.4.57\arch.core\lib\extensions\dom4j.jar;c:\data\arch.inautil
pi.jar;c:\data\arch.inautilus.full.7400.7.4.57\arch.core.servletengine\lib\jackson-core-asl-1.5.5.jar;c:\data\arch.inautilus.full.7400.7.4.57\arch.core.servletengine\lib\jackson-jaxrs-1.5.5.jar;c:\data\arch.inautilus.full.7400.7.
ersistence\lib\commons-collections-2.1.1.jar;c:\data\arch.inautilus.full.7400.7.4.57\arch.ejbpersistence\lib\ehcache-1.2.4.jar;c:\data\arch.inautilus.full.7400.7.4.57\arch.ejbpersistence\lib\hibernate-entitymanager.jar;c:\data\ar
    cp=../../../arch/struts2/lib/commons-collections.jar;c:\data\arch.inautilus.full.7400.7.4.57\arch.core\classes;C:\Data\jdk6\lib\tools.jar;c:\data\arch.inautilus.full.7400.7.4.57\arch.core\classes;c:\data\arch.inautilus.full.7
full.7400.7.4.57\arch.core\lib\looks-win-1.1.2.jar;c:\data\arch.inautilus.full.7400.7.4.57\arch.core\lib\nis-providerutil.jar;c:\data\arch.inautilus.full.7400.7.4.57\arch.core\lib\nis.jar;c:\data\arch.inautilus.full.7400.7.4.57\a
s\xalan.jar;c:\data\arch.inautilus.full.7400.7.4.57\arch.core\lib\extensions\xercesImpl.jar;c:\data\arch.inautilus.full.7400.7.4.57\arch.core\lib\extensions\xsltc.jar;c:\data\arch.inautilus.full.7400.7.4.57\arch.core.servletengin
57\arch.core.servletengine\lib\jstl.jar;c:\data\arch.inautilus.full.7400.7.4.57\arch.core.servletengine\lib\servlet-api.jar;c:\data\arch.inautilus.full.7400.7.4.57\arch.core.servletengine\lib\standard.jar;c:\data\arch.inautilus.f
    cp=C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded\pershing.netxoffice.amps.common\work\pershing.netxoffice.amps.common.WebApplication\__jsp__
```

Comment: What is your question? Is it "Why are these libraries being added to the classpath?"?

Comment: You screenshots are very hard to read. Please copy the text to your question and remove the screenshots.

Comment: @jens : Please find the copied text. The classpath is too big to paste here.. So I just pasted small portion

Comment: @immibis : And I want to know why its getting appended to CLASSPATH

Comment: Changing the download directory from C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded to C:/downloaded helps me to reduce the length of the classpath.. Works fine now

Answer (score 1):

Changing the download directory from **C:\Data\inautilus\Regions\qa\downloaded** to **C:/downloaded** helps me to reduce the length of the classpath.. Works fine now